# Discrete calculation of winding number

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, curves, winding-number

The analytic definition of the winding number of a closed curve and a point is:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_C (\frac{x}{r^2}dy\frac{y}{r^2}dx)$$

Where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$.

In my naivety, by thinking about what the winding number is (how many times does a curve turn around a point). I thought the following would be true:

Given a finite set of ordered points $C = \{p_0, p_1 \dots, p_{n-1}\}$ that describe a polygonal closed curve and a point P. The winding number of that curve is:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum^n_{i=0} A((p_{i} - P), (p_{((i+1) \mod n)} - P))$$

Where $$A(d_1, d_2) = \cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{d1}{|d1|}\cdot\frac{d2}{|d2|}\bigg)$$

Or in plain English, the sum of the angle of every 2 subsequent vectors from the point to a point in the curve.

In other words, angle between (p0 - P) and (p1 - P) plus angle between (p1 - P) and (p2 - P)...

It very much seems that my formula is not equivalent to the analytic form for the discrete case, and I am trying to understand why.

Comment: A closed differentiable curve turns continuously and has contributions all along its path. A polygonal curve does all its turning at discrete points. I imagine that one could do some sort of limiting argument or consider curvature as a measure (which would be discrete in the polygonal case) and recover things appropriately.

Comment: This has to be doable in the discrete case because I know for a fact it's used in computer graphics to calculate inside outside points.

Comment: It is indeed doable, and sensible as a formula. I guess I was just trying to give some idea of how you might get from the analytic form for differentiable curves to the formula you have for polygonal curves.